# Why is the same code slower in lua than in julia?

Tags: lua, julia

When I write out the same code for finding the smallest possible multiple of a number, Julia is much faster than Lua, both taking ~3 seconds & ~23 seconds respectively.

Here is my Julia code:

```
function smallest_multiple(x)
    n = 1
    while true
        for i = 1:x
            if n % i != 0
                break
            elseif i == x
                return n
            end
        end
        n += 1
    end
end

println(smallest_multiple(20))
```

And here is the Lua code:

```lua
function Smallest_Multiple(x)
    local n = 1
    while true do
        for i = 1,x do
            if n % i ~= 0 then
                break
            elseif i == x then
                return n
            end
        end
        n = n + 1
    end
end
```

Is there just a fundamental low-level difference between the languages or an oversight in the code?

Comment: Pretty sure it really depends on the compiler used. I just ran the Lua code in a client that I use (well, uses LuaJIT), and I got the result in less than 4 seconds. But if you use something like Repl.it for compiling, it does take much longer.

Comment: Julia go brrrrr

Comment: Are you sure the lua code was jit-ed? I don't know much about Lua, but I understand that LuaJit is supposed to yield comparable performance to Julia.

Comment: Did... did one of julia's creators just bust out an r/wallstreetbets meme?

Comment: Yes to both. (1) Your usual Lua is not meant for hard-crunching of numbers - LuaJIT can be used for such and gives me around 3 seconds execution time of your code. (2) The major flaw of the code is that the implementation is brutal - it could be way faster in both Julia and Lua.

Comment: Just to add to what the previous commenter said: one of the main purposes of Lua is as a scripting language. It is often used to glue together heavily optimized routines from lower-level languages. For example in game development, Factorio is famous for its low-level optimization which AFAIK is in C, but then the game itself is glued together with Lua. Because of this, speed for the kind of routine in the question is just not a priority for Lua, whereas it is for Julia.